# How to exclude folder from .htaccess redirection rule

Tags: .htaccess

My domain is mainly used for redirects, like: https://example.com/123 to https://example.com/script.php?n=123
The code of the htaccess rule:
`RewriteRule ^([%\ a-zA-Z\d]+)$ script.php?n=$1`

But now I need to make the url https://example.com/blog/ actually open the content from this folder, that is excluded from the redirect. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, so you are hitting link https://example.com/123 which should become https://example.com/blog/ this in browser?

Comment: FYI: That is an internal rewrite, not a redirect.

Comment: Easiest way, IMHO - put a rule in front of it, that matches `/blog/...`, simply does nothing, but ends the rewriting process. `RewriteRule ^blog/ - [END]`

Comment: The stated rule/regex (ie. `^([%\ a-zA-Z\d]+)$`) would not match the URL `/blog/` anyway, so it's already excluded? Maybe the problem is elsewhere in the file, or perhaps you are (erroneously) requesting `/blog` and not `/blog/`?